# How to make Django template render a set of results from views and keep calling view for more results without refreshing page

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a twitter application which fetches tweets from twitter REST API based on a search query. Now from these results, I want to display only those tweets on frontend which have more than 2 retweets. For my queries, for every 100 tweets there are only a couple of such tweets which satisfy this criteria. So to display 100 such tweets which have more than 2 retweet, I must process 5-10k tweets. But maximum of 100 tweets can be fetched in a single API call.

Now if I fetch 5-10k tweets in my `views.py`, process them, extract tweets which I need, and then pass it as a context to be rendered to django template - (or I just pass api result as is to template and display only tweets which fit criteria), - then it obviously wont work since user cant wait for site to load till all tweets are processed. Mostly a timeout would occur.

So is there a way by which I could:

1. Fetch first 100 tweets in a call in views.
2. Render the tweets which satisfy criteria on template (front-end)
3. Keep `views.py` running api calls in background and keep rendering the tweets which satisfy criteria below current set of results on template, without refreshing the page.

Twitter library I am using is Tweepy.

*views.py*:

```
import tweepy
def index(request):
    try:
        query = 'qwerty'
        ###
        # Twitter Api authorization code here
        ###
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, count=100).items(100)
        context = {'tweets': results,
                   'query':query,}
    except (KeyError):
        raise
    else:
        return render(request, 'tweets/index.html', context)
def index(request):
```

*Template*:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    {% if tweet.retweet_count >=2 %}
        //Display the tweets
        Tweet: {{ tweet.text }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or Is there a way by which I can make the call from django template itself dynamically? But would that render the results and load whatever is fetched so far and make rest calls after page is loaded, or simply wait for all calls to be made before page is loaded fully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072356/2932244) which Deniz KAPLAN has provided will not work in your case since you are using Twitter API. Twitter does not follow the process of pagination. Pagination is useful when the data you want to iterate through is fixed and does not keep updating.

Check out this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) to see how Twitter's timeline works.

Anyways, what you need to do is make use of the `max_id` variable. `max_id` is basically the id of the last tweet that you've fetched.

So, when you make an AJAX call, the data which you should be sending is the `max_id` value.

```
...
data: {'max_id': 3, 'query': 'qwerty'} //Append additional data if required.
...
```

Now, make sure you have another view function to process your AJAX requests. The function will look somewhat like this.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse

def ajax_tweets(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        max_id = int(request.GET['max_id'])
        query = request.GET['query']

        ###
        # Perform API auth requirements
        ###

        tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, max_id=max_id, count=100).items(100)
        json = simplejson.dumps(tweets)

        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

Now, in the `success` function of the AJAX call, the browser will fetch JSON object sent. And then you can make the required changes.

```
...
success: function(data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     //Perform DOM manipulations to append your tweets to your page
},
...
```

You can add a loop around your AJAX function with a condition depending upon the number of tweets you want displayed on the page.

I hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: Excellent explaination, Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Can you call this view from template via AJAX? You can use pagination if you can use this with AJAX. Just need to get two parameters (start, end) from ajax request. In your template, you can call an AJAX request like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '{% url "ajax-filter-tweets" %}',
         data: {'start':100, 'end':200},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data) {
         //append new tweets via js code here
         // at the end send another ajax if more tweets in queue
    },
    error: function(){
        //your error handling here
        }
    });
});
```

you can send $.ajax() function to this view's url and on it's success part you can call new ajax function with start and end indexes. You need to customise your filter view or generate a new one for ajax requests(from start index to end index result filtering). You can set timeout between the ajax request via javascript. You can also search this type of issues with "pagination" keyword. [Pagination Example](http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/jquery-infinite-scroll-flask-bootstrap/) may be help you for sample codes.

Comment: I thought that this issue would be addressed by AJAX but I have 0 knowledge for the same, so wasn't sure. I am not sure what you mean by pagination, I dont want to implement pages on site, simply need to put up 100 tweets in single page. Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope this will help you to begin. Only thing I have to mention is you can easily change html page according to AJAX result. In success function of AJAX is where your view return filtered content and you need to append new tweets to html container of older tweets. You can use 'div' tag to surround all tweets. Django also has endless pagination library (if you want to check: https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)